# FilterRegistrationBean necessary to enable CORS support with Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cors, preflight

My resource server is secured by OAuth2 and uses this CORS configuration:

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource()
{
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}

@Bean
FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> corsFilter(CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource)
{
    CorsFilter corsFilter = new CorsFilter(corsConfigurationSource);

    FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    bean.setFilter(corsFilter);
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return bean;
}
```

The configuration handles preflight requests as expected, but i'm wondering why it is necessary to create a custom FilterRegistrationBean and set its order, instead of using the official CORS support of [HttpSecurity.cors()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#cors--) documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/cors.html):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.cors();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource()
    {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

The above configuration doesn't handle preflight requests properly, i guess the CORS filter has lower precendece than the spring security filter.

[image]

Is there a downside of using the first FilterRegistrationBean version or why does the official cors configuration not work properly? Did i make a mistake in configuring the offical way?

I am using Spring Boot 2 with `spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure`, but got the same behaviour in Spring Boot 1.5.x.

Comment: @dur Thank you for your comment. You're right, i used the default order of 100, changing this results in the expected behaviour. If you like write an answer and i will accept it. Do you have any recommendation for a specific order value or is [Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Ordered.html#HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) the way to go?

Comment: Just found the information [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableResourceServer.html): The EnableResourceServer annotation creates a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with a hard-coded Order of 3, guess any value below should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WebSecurityConfig` class is never used for any request, because the default order is 100, see [`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html):

> ```java
> @Order(value=100)
> public abstract class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
> extends java.lang.Object
> implements WebSecurityConfigurer<WebSecurity>
> ```

and the default order of the resource server configuration is 3, see [`EnableResourceServer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableResourceServer.html):

> The annotation creates a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` with a hard-coded `Order` (of 3).

If you want to use your `WebSecurityConfig` class you have to change the order to a value lesser than 3. But be careful, because you could hide your resource server configuration.

If your application is also an authorization server, you have to be careful, too. Your authorization server configuration annotated with [`EnableAuthorizationServer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableAuthorizationServer.html) could be not used. The default order of authorization server's security configuration is 0, see [`AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/ec215f79f4f73f8bb5d4b8a3ff9abe15b3335866/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration.java#L42).

If you only want to add CORS support to your resource server configuration, it is easier to override [`ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter#configure(HttpSecurity http)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter.html#configure(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity)).