# Spring Boot Security with Basic Auth and OAuth Order Issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to implement a simple spring boot project. I got several REST-Endpoints which I've to secure differently. One has to be secured by Basic Auth, another one with OAuth and one with a custom security implementation.

REST-Endpoints:

- /basic/auth
- /application/secure (oauth)
- /application/secure2 (own implementation)

From tutorials, I know I've to set the order of the security adapters. My first intention was to set the order in steps of ten (e.g. `@Order(10)`, `@Order(20)`) in case I need to add other security filters in between. By doing so I investigated the following behavior:

- If I add the basic auth filter with `@Order(10)` and an OAuth filter with `@Order(20)` only the OAuth filter works.
- If I add the basic auth filter with `@Order(1)` or `@Order(2)` and an OAuth filter with `@Order(4)` both filters works.
- If I add a filter to `@Order(3)` I receive an error which says, that order 3 is already in use and cannot be configured twice.

So there is a default spring security adapter (or whatever) which has the default order 3. I thought I disable every default spring security behavior by adding `@EnableWebSecurity`. After I did not find an answer by google my questions would be:

- Am I doing the right things?
- What is this security adapter with order 3 by spring?
- Does the default security adapter block my basic auth implementation?

WebSecurityConfig:

```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
   public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Order(10)
    @Configuration
    public class BasicAuthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Value("${security.user.password}")
        private String password;
        @Value("${security.user.name}")
        private String username;

        private static final String ROLE_ADMIN = "ADMIN";

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(username).password(password).roles(ROLE_ADMIN);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable();
            http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/basic/**", "/") //
                    .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated() //
                    .and().httpBasic();
        }
    }

    @Order(20)
    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    protected static class Oauth2ServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Filter called");
            // @formatter:off
            http.csrf().disable();
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/application/**").authenticated()
                    // .antMatchers(GET, "/application/secure").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated(); 
            // @formatter:on
        }

     // offline token validator

    }
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49429040/5277820

Comment: mh, I still don't get why a new `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` wouldn't be called if the `order` is set to a bigger value then 3. Shouldn't this be called afterward or match when the request path is called? Does the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which is created by the `@EnableResourceServer` overwrites every other `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`? This would mean I'm limited to two filter while using a `@EnableResourceServer`.

Comment: It is important to understand, that only one configuration is applied. The first one in the chain **matching the request**. All others are not applied.

Comment: But a call to `/basic/auth` does not match a call to `/application/secure`. So even if the basic auth filter got an `order` bigger than 3 it should be matching, shouldn't it?

Comment: Why do both configurations match `/**` ? For one it's `/basic/**` and `/` and for the other one its `/application/**`. A call to everything else should be denied, shouldn't it?

Comment: No, for `BasicAuthConfig` it is `/basic/**` and `/` and for `Oauth2ServerConfig` it is `/**`.

Comment: Could you please explain why `/**` is a matcher for `Oauth2ServerConfig `?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33603156/spring-security-multiple-http-config-not-working/33608459#33608459 and  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41527591/5277820.

Comment: I tested and read a little bit more. `Oauth2ServerConfig` matches `/**` because there is no requestMatcher. So if I want to have filters after the `order` of `3`. I need to add a request filter to `/application/**`.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but if anyone is still wondering what the issue is, here are my observations:

- [`@EnableResourceServer`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/ResourceServerConfiguration.java) imports [`ResourceServerConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/ResourceServerConfiguration.java), which has an order of 3.
- There are ways that may allow you to add more than 2 filters before the `order 3` resource server configurer, for instance

  - by giving some of them negative order values (Although I don't suppose negative values would be any special, one would need to take into account other implicit [web security configurers](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/WebSecurityConfigurer.java) -- for instance the one with order 0 -- enabled by default. This however means there is a possibility of collision between filters in different versions of the framework as new features are introduced);
  - by adding them as resource configurers (The `ResourceServerConfiguration` class does not add any request matchers, but enforces a fallback to `anyRequest().authenticated()` if the user has not configured anything).
- For a better understanding on how paths are matched in the configured request matchers, you can take a quick glance at [Ant path patterns](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns).